# Convert array of elements to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How I can convert a array (in a column) with a set of elements in a JSON dataset to multiple columns with python, spark or pandas?
The data is structured in this form:

```
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- idAccount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- infractionType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- responseTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- transactionCode: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm expecting some kind of this:

| id | idAccount |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value |

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. See [ask]. Do your own programming at first and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

an array of structs can be exploded into columns using the `inline` sql function.

here's an example of how it works.

```py
data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([([(1234, 2345, 3456), (4321, 5432, 6543)],)], 
                                 'items array<struct<id: int, id_acc: int, foo: int>>'
                                 )

# +----------------------------------------+
# |items                                   |
# +----------------------------------------+
# |[{1234, 2345, 3456}, {4321, 5432, 6543}]|
# +----------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- items: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- id_acc: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)

# explode and create new columns using struct fields - using `inline`
data_sdf. \
    selectExpr('inline(items)'). \
    show()

# +----+------+----+
# |  id|id_acc| foo|
# +----+------+----+
# |1234|  2345|3456|
# |4321|  5432|6543|
# +----+------+----+
```

you can further just `select()` the required fields after the explosion.

Comment: This one is better since it avoids bulky coding.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark SQL, you can access the item in `ArrayType` or `MapType` column by using `getItem`. For example, you want to get the value of the id of first item, you can use `df.select(func.getItem(0).getItem('id'))`